# Accesing the Sharepoint Online Document Getting Error The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: document-library, azure

I am accessing the document from the SharePoint Doc Library from the Azure Web API Hosted on the Azure.
List items I can access properly. But, when I am trying to read the document I'm getting the error message

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Below is the code which I have written.

```
var userToken = this.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
var newToken = await GetSharePointAccessToken(doc.sharePointUrl, userToken);
using (var context = new ClientContext(doc.sharePointUrl))
{
    context.ExecutingWebRequest +=
        (s, e) => e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add(
        "Authorization", "Bearer " + newToken);
    var web = context.Web;
    var oList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Employee");

    ListItem item = oList.GetItemById(doc.docID);
    context.Load(item);
    context.Load(item, i => i.File);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    FileInformation fInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, item["FileRef"].ToString());
    var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileRef);

}
```

At this line I am getting the exception:

```
FileInformation fInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, item["FileRef"].ToString());
```